# Swift Coredata Wont Save Due To Error Code 1580

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am pretty new to using Core Data and I am having trouble saving my context. Below is a method that gets a teams schedule from my database which then stores the game in the Schedule Core Data entity. But the problem is that the game object won't save when i call context.save(nil). Note that i call the getTeamSchedule() from another method called login() which you can find below.

```
func getTeamSchedule()
{
    let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as!AppDelegate
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    // check if a teams schedule exists in database
    if(doesTeamScheduleExist() == true)
    {
        return
    }
    else
    {
        // download schedule
        let dao = DatabaseRequests()
        let request = dao.buildURLRequest("appGetSchedule.php", postStringWithValue: "teamId=\(self.id)")

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request)
        { data, response, error in
            if(error == nil)
            {
                var err:NSError?
                var scheduleData = (NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers, error: &err)) as! NSArray

                let entSchdl = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Schedule", inManagedObjectContext: context)
                let entTeam = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Team", inManagedObjectContext: context)

                // loop through data set
                for(var index = 0; index < scheduleData.count; index++)
                {
                    /* I Grab My Data From JSON Here*/

                    var homeTeam : Team
                    var awayTeam : Team

                    // check for home team in DB
                    if(self.doesTeamExistByString(homeId) == true)
                    {
                        // get team
                        homeTeam = self.getStoredTeamByString(homeId)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // create team 
                        homeTeam = self.createNewTeam(homeId, tName: homeName)
                    }

                    //check for away team in DB
                    if(self.doesTeamExistByString(awayId) == true)
                    {
                        // get team
                        awayTeam = self.getStoredTeamByString(awayId)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        awayTeam = self.createNewTeam(awayId, tName: awayName)
                    }

                    // create a set to store the home and away team objects

                    // create a set to store the home and away team object
                    let teamSet:NSSet = ([awayTeam, homeTeam])

                    // fetch level object
                    let lvl = self.getStoredLevelByString(level)

                    var newGame = Schedule(entity: entSchdl!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
                    newGame.id = gameId
                    newGame.homeTeamID = homeId
                    newGame.awayTeamID = awayId
                    newGame.levelID = level
                    newGame.date = dateAsNSDate!
                    newGame.toTeam = teamSet
                    newGame.toLevel = lvl

                    println(newGame)
```

At this point, I print the newGame object which shows that all required attributes and relationships are filled so i run context.save() but the newGame Object is not saved

```
                    var saveError:NSError?

                    //save context
                    context.save(&saveError)
                    println(saveError)
                }
            }
            else
            {
                println("error =\(error)")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Here is the newGame Object

```
<Schedule: 0x7f8f8ae89110> (entity: Schedule; id: 0x7f8f8ae89180 <x-coredata:///Schedule/t3FF77C1C-6BFD-41F9-9F7E-04D851B11EAB3> ; data: {
awayTeamID = 13;
date = "2015-06-15 05:00:00 +0000";
homeTeamID = 13;
id = 2;
levelID = 1;
toGameLog =     (
);
toLevel = "0xd000000000340004 <x-coredata://1B97E1D1-833F-4978-B1A8-05C4BE90A80A/Level/p13>";
toTeam =     (
    "0xd000000000840006 <x-coredata://1B97E1D1-833F-4978-B1A8-05C4BE90A80A/Team/p33>"
);
})
```

And Here is the Error I am getting

```
Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1580 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1580.)" UserInfo=0x7f8f8ae8cfc0 {NSValidationErrorObject=<Schedule: 0x7f8f8ae89110> (entity: Schedule; id: 0x7f8f8ae89180 <x-coredata:///Schedule/t3FF77C1C-6BFD-41F9-9F7E-04D851B11EAB3> ; data: {
awayTeamID = 13;
date = "2015-06-15 05:00:00 +0000";
homeTeamID = 13;
id = 2;
levelID = 1;
toGameLog =     (
);
toLevel = "0xd000000000340004 <x-coredata://1B97E1D1-833F-4978-B1A8-05C4BE90A80A/Level/p13>";
toTeam =     (
    "0xd000000000840006 <x-coredata://1B97E1D1-833F-4978-B1A8-05C4BE90A80A/Team/p33>"
);
}), NSValidationErrorValue=Relationship 'toTeam' on managed object (0x7f8f8ae89110) <Schedule: 0x7f8f8ae89110> (entity: Schedule; id: 0x7f8f8ae89180 <x-coredata:///Schedule/t3FF77C1C-6BFD-41F9-9F7E-04D851B11EAB3> ; data: {
awayTeamID = 13;
date = "2015-06-15 05:00:00 +0000";
homeTeamID = 13;
id = 2;
levelID = 1;
toGameLog =     (
);
toLevel = "0xd000000000340004 <x-coredata://1B97E1D1-833F-4978-B1A8-05C4BE90A80A/Level/p13>";
toTeam =     (
    "0xd000000000840006 <x-coredata://1B97E1D1-833F-4978-B1A8-05C4BE90A80A/Team/p33>"
);
}) with objects {(
<Team: 0x7f8f8ae87120> (entity: Team; id: 0xd000000000840006 <x-coredata://1B97E1D1-833F-4978-B1A8-05C4BE90A80A/Team/p33> ; data: {
id = 13;
name = "Ghost Team";
toDefenseLineup = "<relationship fault: 0x7f8f8ae80480 'toDefenseLineup'>";
toPlayer = "<relationship fault: 0x7f8f8ae804c0 'toPlayer'>";
toSchedule =     (
    "0x7f8f8ae89180 <x-coredata:///Schedule/t3FF77C1C-6BFD-41F9-9F7E-04D851B11EAB3>"
);
})
)}, NSValidationErrorKey=toTeam, NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1580.)})
```

I have tried to look up the error code 1580 but can't find anything, if anybody has any resources or knows what the problem is i would appreciate it.

Also out of curiosity what does this mean

```
relationship fault: 0x7f8f8ae804c0 'toPlayer';
```

Comment: It would be good to know what error `context.save()` is generating. Can you make an error variable `var saveError: NSError?` and try saving with that error `context.save(&saveError)`. Then after the save, print the error `println(saveError)` and report back with what that tells you?

Comment: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1580

Comment: I added the error as well as a print of the newGame object

Comment: I'm starting to this the issue may be the way your data model is set up. Specifically, the way you have your relationships between entities configured. Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325676/core-data-deleteobject-crashes-are-delete-rules-the-cause). While I don't think it will be a quick-switch answer to your question, it may get you onto the right track.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is not your `newGame` object, but your `homeTeam` and `awayTeam` objects.  Specifically, these two lines:

```
    var homeTeam = Team(entity: entTeam!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
    var awayTeam = Team(entity: entTeam!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
```

create two new objects.  In your `if` statements you reassign these vars to either newly created or newly fetched objects.  In either case, the objects created by the lines above do not have any attributes set.  When you save the context, these objects fail the validation and trigger the error.

Change the above two lines to:

```
    var homeTeam : Team
    var awayTeam : Team
```

That will declare the two vars without creating new Team objects.

Comment: I tried you fix but still get there error. I posted the error in the question. The error code is 1580.

Comment: The 1580 error code represents a "relationship lacks minimum count error".  If you look, `toTeam` shows only one object - have you specified a minimum number in the data model?  Clearly `teamSet` includes two items - but could they be the same?  NSSet will only store one if they are duplicates.  Put another way, is `homeId` = `awayId`?